# Is it ok to use bounty for rewarding an answerer?

Tags: discussion, bounty

From [faq on bounties](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty) I see that bounties are primarily for increasing exposure and improving possibility of attracting a good answer.

Sometimes I am in position that I have received a very nice answer and I wish to give some reputation to the answerer as reward. (Usually if I think that the answer deserves more reputation points than from the upvotes it gained.)

- Is it ok to use bounties for this purpose?
- If I want to use bounty in this way, should I indicate somewhere that this is my intention?

Of course, I understand that adding a bounty might well also be useful for me, not only for the answerer - the question will be featured which might attract some upvotes and perhaps even some more useful answers.

(I have feeling that something like this has been discussed on meta, but I did not find such question now. So maybe it was just tangential issue mentioned in some post or in a comment in a question related to something else.)

Comment: Keep in mind you can leave the bounty open for a while before you award the answerer too, so that more people see his cool answer.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Yes.**

When you post a bounty on a question, this is in fact listed as one of the options for why you are putting a bounty on the question:

> Reward existing answer:
>
> One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty.